# Specifying font size with LoadClassWithOptions causes error

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

When I specify font size with `LoadClassWithOptions`, the main document gives error:

> File `.cls' not found.

The custom class file is in the same folder as the main file. What I am doing wrong?

**myclass.cls**

```
\LoadClassWithOptions[12pt]{book} % --> gives error
%\LoadClassWithOptions{book} % --> compiles
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2019/06/03 custom class file]
```

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}
Hi
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Tex version: TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018)

OS: Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Try `\LoadClassWithOptions{12pt}{book}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik In this case, I get another error: `File `12pt.cls' not found`

Comment: Oops, sorry. `\LoadClassWithOptions{book}{12pt}` then.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Then I get this error: `myclass.cls: Missing \begin{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just wish to load the `book` class with the `12pt` option and none that the user has specified, then you can just write

```
\LoadClass[12pt]{book}
```

If on the other hand you also want to pass on the options the user provided to your class, then the method is

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[12pt]{book}
```

Thus `myclass.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2019/06/03 custom class file]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[12pt]{book}
```

and `test.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{myclass}

\begin{document}
Hi
\end{document}
```

results in `book.cls` being load with both the `a4paper` option and the `12pt` option.

`\LoadClassWithOptions` is for loading a class only with options the user passes on.  It takes an optional argument specifying a oldest date for the version of the class.  See [`clsguide.pdf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clsguide) for more details.